# Lotus Notes Cannot Get subject from .Value or ColumnValues '451 Error

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, lotus-notes

I seem to be getting the same "'451 Property let procedure not defined and property get procedure did not return an object" run time error when trying to get the subject of my emails from Lotus Notes. I have tried by using both `GetFirstItem("subject")` as well as `ColumnValues(5)` but both drop the same error.

The below is the `GetFirstItem` method, `NSubject` in this case does hold the variable Values(0) with the subject line captured correctly. I just can't seem to figure out how to pull it and use it.

```
Sub Test_subject()

Dim NSession As Object
Dim NMailDb As Object
Dim NFolder As Object
Dim NView As Object
Dim NDocument As Object
Dim NSubject As Object
Dim NItem As Variant

Set NSession = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession")
Call NSession.Initialize("password")

Set NMailDb = NSession.GetDatabase("Server", "Directory")
   If Not NMailDb.IsOpen = True Then
   Call NMailDb.Open
End If

Set NFolder = NMailDb.GetView("($Inbox)")
Set NView = NFolder.CreateViewNav()

Set NDocument = NView.GetLastDocument
Set NItem = NDocument.Document
Set NSubject = NItem.GetFirstItem("subject")
   MsgBox (NSubject.Values(0))
End Sub
```

Changing to `.ColumnValues(6)` which contains the correct value also drops the same error. I'm clearly not understanding something but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
Set NDocument = NView.GetLastDocument
NItem = NDocument.ColumnValues(6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `.GetFirstItem("subject")` with `.GetItemValue("Subject")` works fine for this. I would like to know however why the above doesn't work because I feel like pulling `.ColumnValues` may be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining about this line:

```
Set NItem = NDocument.Document
```

You had previously assigned `Set NDocument = NView.GetLastDocument`, so NDocument is an object in the [NotesDocument class](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/10.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDOCUMENT_CLASS.html). `NDocument.Document` throws an error because there is no Document property in the NotesDocument class.

This line of code is pointless, anyhow. You already have your NotesDocument object. And it's kind of weird to try to assign a NotesDocument object to a variable named NItem. You should be using an object variable named NItem only if you are using the GetFirstItem method.

Your next line of code needs to be:

```
Set NSubject = NDocument.GetFirstItem("subject")
```

instead of

```
Set NSubject = NItem.GetFirstItem("subject")
```

And if you want to use ColumnValues, it will be `NDocument.ColumnValues`, not `NItem.ColumnValues`.

Comment: Adjusting NSubject to be ```Set NSubject = NDocument.GetFirstItem("subject")``` drops an Object doesn't support this property or method error. And GetLastDocument does(??) have ```Document``` that seems to contain ```Items``` which is why I assume ```.GetItemValue``` works for me using it from ```NItem```(?)

Comment: Did you remove the line `Set NItem = NDocument.Document?`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, NView.GetLastDocument gives a NotesViewEntry. The variable names are rather confusing, NDocument is an entry and NItem is a document...

Comment: There is a GetLastEntry method in NotesViewEntryCollection, but NotesView.GetLastDocument returns a NotesDocument.

https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_GETLASTDOCUMENT_METHOD_VIEW.html

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that seems really off in your code is the declaration of NItem as Variant, and not as Object. Could you change that and try again?